# How to remove duplicate lines from a file

Tags: unix, command-line, duplicates

I have a tool that generates tests and predicts the output.  The idea is that if I have a failure I can compare the prediction to the actual output and see where they diverged.  The problem is the actual output contains some lines twice, which confuses `diff`.  I want to remove the duplicates, so that I can compare them easily.  Basically, something like `sort -u` but without the sorting.

Is there any unix command line tool that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[uniq(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq)

SYNOPSIS

> uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]

DESCRIPTION

> Discard all but one of successive identical lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

Or, if you want to remove non-adjacent duplicate lines as well, this fragment of perl will do it:

```
while(<>) {
    print $_ if (!$seen{$_});
    $seen{$_}=1;
}
```

Comment: The Perl answer only works if you want the first item.  The last would be a different solution.

Comment: And for those who don't know how to use Perl, this is all you need to type:

  perl -pe 'print unless $seen{$_}++' [INPUT] > OUTPUT

Comment: @Xetuis, they're the same line :) If you do want the last line, just set the seen entry to the line number, don't print in the loop, then and print them out in order of line number at the end. But I don't think that's neded in this case.

Comment: @reinierpost, yep, I can never recall the command line options to do that so I tend to resort to full scripts...

Answer (score 25):

Complementary to the `uniq` answers, which work great if you don't mind `sort`ing your file first.  If you need to remove non-adjacent lines (or if you want to remove duplicates without rearranging your file), the following Perl one-liner should do it (stolen from [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/42005-remove-duplicated-lines-without-sort.html)):

```
cat textfile | perl -ne '$H{$_}++ or print'
```

Comment: I think this is a neat answer.  Been programming in Perl for about 6 years now and wouldn't have thought of something so concise

Comment: The Perl part is really nifty. This does, however, qualify for the "Useless Use of cat" award :-) (see http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Just use "<textfile" at the end.

Comment: I'd never heard of that award!  Yeah, I do use cat rather gratuitously sometimes; I have no idea idea why "cat x | " looks any better than "< x" to me.. it just does :)  It may have something to do with the fact that I very often redirect stdout as well, and "./prog < x > y" makes my eyes bleed :P

Comment: Useless use of cat award!  Use perl -ne ...whatever... textfile

Comment: To get only non-unique lines from an unsorted input, based on @MattJ's answer: `perl -ne '0==$H{$_}++ or print'`. Note that it will print the second occurrence - the first duplicate, that is.

Comment: If you want to keep blank lines: `perl -ne 'if (/\S/) {$H{$_}++ or print} else {print}'`.

Comment: This is a great answer, but did no one notice the OP's "but without the sorting" request?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an awk implementation, incase the environment does not have / allow perl (haven't seen one yet)!  PS: If there are more than one duplicate lines, then this prints duplicate outputs.

```
awk '{

# Cut out the key on which duplicates are to be determined.
key = substr($0,2,14)

#If the key is not seen before, store in array,else print
if ( ! s[key] )
    s[key] = 1;
else
    print key;
}'
```

Comment: If you're just looking at the entire line being the key, this is analogous to the perl solutions: `awk '!c[$0]++' file`

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in removing *adjacent* duplicate lines, use `uniq`.

If you want to remove *all* duplicate lines, not just adjacent ones, then it's trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with while I was waiting for an answer here (though the first (and accepted) answer came in about 2 minutes).  I used this substitution in `VIM`:

```
%s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/
```

Which means: look for lines where after the newline we have the same as before, and replace them only with what we captured in the first line.

`uniq` is definitely easier, though.