# How to delete duplicate lines in a file without sorting it in Unix

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, sed, awk

Is there a way to delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?

I can do it with `sort -u` and `uniq` commands, but I want to use `sed` or `awk`.

Is that possible?

Comment: if you mean consecutive duplicates then `uniq` alone is enough.

Comment: and otherwise, I believe it's possible with `awk`, but will be quite resource consuming on bigger files.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/24324350 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11532157 have interesting answers which should ideally be migrated here.

Comment: @tripleee especially the [`cat -n | sort -k2 -u | ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639730/10971581) one, which can cope with files that are too large to be processed in-memory

Answer (score 394, accepted):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file.txt
```

`seen` is an associative array that AWK will pass every line of the file to. If a line isn't in the array then `seen[$0]` will evaluate to false. The `!` is the logical NOT operator and will invert the false to true. AWK will print the lines where the expression evaluates to true.

The `++` increments `seen` so that `seen[$0] == 1` after the first time a line is found and then `seen[$0] == 2`, and so on.
AWK evaluates everything but `0` and `""` (empty string) to true. If a duplicate line is placed in `seen` then `!seen[$0]` will evaluate to false and the line will not be written to the output.

Comment: To save it in a file we can do this ```awk '!seen[$0]++' merge_all.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: An important caveat here: if you need to do this for multiple files, and you tack more files on the end of the command, or use a wildcard… the 'seen' array will fill up with duplicate lines from ALL the files. If you instead want to treat each file independently, you'll need to do something like `for f in *.txt; do gawk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' "$f"; done`

Comment: @NickK9 that de-duping cumulatively across multiple files is awesome in itself. Nice tip

Comment: It also works thanks to the fact that the result of '++' operator is not the value after  increment, but the previous value.

Answer (score 37):

From http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt:
(Please don't ask me how this works ;-) )

```
 # delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq").
 # First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.
 sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'

 # delete duplicate, nonconsecutive lines from a file. Beware not to
 # overflow the buffer size of the hold space, or else use GNU sed.
 sed -n 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P'
```

Comment: geekery;-) +1, but resource consumption is inavoidable.

Comment: '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' means "If you're not at the last line, read in another line. Now look at what you have and if it ISN'T stuff followed by a newline and then the same stuff again, print out the stuff. Now delete the stuff (up to the newline)."

Comment: 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P' means, roughly, "Append the whole hold space this line, then if you see a duplicated line throw the whole thing out, otherwise copy the whole mess back into the hold space and print the first part (which is the line you just read."

Comment: Is the `$!` part necessary? Doesn't `sed 'N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'` do the same thing? I can't come up with an example where the two are different on my machine (fwiw I did try an empty line at the end with both versions and they were both fine).

Comment: The second solution doesn't work for me (on GNU sed 4.2.1), on a test file with only lowercase English letters and spaces. However, replacing `[ -~]` with `.` or `[^\n]` or even `[ -z{|}~]` (the exact same set of characters) does the job. If anyone can explain the difference, that would be nice...

Comment: Almost 7 years later and no one answered @amichair ... <sniff> makes me sad. ;) Anyways, `[ -~]` represents a range of ASCII characters from 0x20 (space) to 0x7E (tilde). These are considered [the _printable_ ASCII characters](https://www.ascii-code.com/) (linked page also has 0x7F/delete but that doesn't seem right). That makes the solution broken for anyone not using ASCII or anyone using, say, tab characters.. The more portable `[^\n]` includes a whole lot more characters...all of 'em except one, in fact.

Comment: Thanks for caring, @BLayer :-) I think I may have been asking about the second case - `[ -z{|}~]` and `[ -~]` seem to select the same range of ASCII characters, yet one worked and the other did not...

Comment: @amichair  You'll never walk aloooone. :D  Alas, I think I mistakenly read "space" as "whitespace" and assumed you had a Tab somewhere in there. Maybe it was a bug in sed. Can you still reproduce? I can't with gnu sed 4.4. Only other thing that comes to mind is `[..]` ranges being non-portable across different locales (i.e. LC_COLLATE, fixed by setting `LC_ALL=C`) but that seems like a stretch esp. since it sounds like you know what you're doing. Sorry for raising false hopes. ;)

Comment: @BLayer Nope, on GNU sed 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 `[ -~]` works for me but `[ -z{|}~]` does not in the second command (non-consecutive lines, e.g. pipe `echo -e "1\n2\n3\n1\n4\n3\n"` into the command).

Answer (score 25):

Perl one-liner similar to [jonas's AWK solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix/1444448#1444448):

```
perl -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' file
```

This variation removes trailing white space before comparing:

```
perl -lne 's/\s*$//; print if ! $x{$_}++' file
```

This variation edits the file in-place:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' file
```

This variation edits the file in-place, and makes a backup `file.bak`:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if ! $x{$_}++' file
```

Comment: How to redirect otuput to stdout? Piping does not work with this approach.

Comment: My original answer outputs to stdout, as well as the first variation

Answer (score 8):

**An alternative way using Vim (Vi compatible)**:

Delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file:

`vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.*)\n\1$/d' +wq`

Delete duplicate, nonconsecutive and nonempty lines from a file:

`vim -esu NONE +'g/\v^(.+)$\_.{-}^\1$/d' +wq`

Answer (score 6):

The one-liner that [Andre Miller posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix/1444433#1444433) works except for recent versions of sed when the input file ends with a blank line and no characterss.  On my Mac my CPU just spins.

This is an infinite loop if the last line is blank and doesn't have any characterss:

`sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'`

It doesn't hang, but you lose the last line:

`sed '$d;N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'`

The explanation is at the very end of the [sed FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/editor-faq/sed/):

> The GNU sed maintainer felt that despite the portability problems
> this would cause, changing the N command to print (rather than
> delete) the pattern space was more consistent with one's intuitions
> about how a command to "append the Next line" *ought* to behave.
> Another fact favoring the change was that "{N;command;}" will
> delete the last line if the file has an odd number of lines, but
> print the last line if the file has an even number of lines.

> To convert scripts which used the former behavior of N (deleting
> the pattern space upon reaching the EOF) to scripts compatible with
> all versions of sed, **change a lone "N;" to "$d;N;"**.

Answer (score 5):

#### The first solution is also from http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n2\n3\n3\n3\n4\n4\n4\n4\n5' |sed -nr '$!N;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P;D'
1
2
3
4
5
```

The core idea is:

> Print *only* once of each duplicate consecutive lines at its *last* appearance and use the D command to implement the *loop*.

Explanation:

1. `$!N;`: if the current line is *not* the last line, use the `N` command to read the next line into the *pattern space*.
2. `/^(.*)\n\1$/!P`: if the contents of the current *pattern space* is two *duplicate strings* separated by `\n`, which means the next line is the *same* with current line, we can *not* print it according to our core idea; otherwise, which means the current line is the *last* appearance of all of its duplicate consecutive lines. We can now use the `P` command to print the characters in the current *pattern space* until `\n` (`\n` also printed).
3. `D`: we use the `D` command to delete the characters in the current *pattern space* until `\n` (`\n` also deleted), and then the content of *pattern space* is the next line.
4. and the `D` command will force `sed` to jump to its *first* command `$!N`, but *not* read the next line from a file or standard input stream.

#### The second solution is easy to understand (from myself):

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n2\n3\n3\n3\n4\n4\n4\n4\n5' |sed -nr 'p;:loop;$!N;s/^(.*)\n\1$/\1/;tloop;D'
1
2
3
4
5
```

The core idea is:

> print *only* once of each duplicate consecutive lines at its *first* appearance and use the `:` command and `t` command to implement LOOP.

Explanation:

1. read a new line from the input stream or file and print it once.
2. use the `:loop` command to set a *label* named *loop*.
3. use `N` to read the next line into the *pattern space*.
4. use `s/^(.*)\n\1$/\1/` to delete the current line if the next line is the same with the current line. We use the `s` command to do the *delete* action.
5. if the `s` command is executed successfully, then use the *tloop* command to force `sed` to jump to the *label* named *loop*, which will do the same loop to the next lines until there are no duplicate consecutive lines of the line which is *latest printed*; otherwise, use the `D` command to `delete` the line which is the same with the *latest-printed line*, and force `sed` to jump to the first command, which is the `p` command. The content of the current *pattern space* is the next new line.

Comment: same command on Windows with busybox: `busybox echo -e "1\n2\n2\n3\n3\n3\n4\n4\n4\n4\n5" | busybox sed -nr "$!N;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P;D"`

Answer (score 2):

*[uniq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq)* would be fooled by trailing spaces and tabs. In order to emulate how a human makes comparison, I am trimming all trailing spaces and tabs before comparison.

I think that the `$!N;` needs curly braces or else it continues, and that is the cause of the infinite loop.

I have Bash 5.0 and sed 4.7 in [Ubuntu 20.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.10_(Groovy_Gorilla)) (Groovy Gorilla). The second one-liner did not work, at the character set match.

The are three variations. The first is to eliminate adjacent repeat lines, the second to eliminate repeat lines wherever they occur, and the third to eliminate all but the last instance of lines in file.

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/evmjsNbe)

```
# First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.
# Emulate human eyes on trailing spaces and tabs by trimming those.
# Use after norepeat() to dedupe blank lines.

dedupe() {
 sed -E '
  $!{
   N;
   s/[ \t]+$//;
   /^(.*)\n\1$/!P;
   D;
  }
 ';
}

# Delete duplicate, nonconsecutive lines from a file. Ignore blank
# lines. Trailing spaces and tabs are trimmed to humanize comparisons
# squeeze blank lines to one

norepeat() {
 sed -n -E '
  s/[ \t]+$//;
  G;
  /^(\n){2,}/d;
  /^([^\n]+).*\n\1(\n|$)/d;
  h;
  P;
  ';
}

lastrepeat() {
 sed -n -E '
  s/[ \t]+$//;
  /^$/{
   H;
   d;
  };
  G;
  # delete previous repeated line if found
  s/^([^\n]+)(.*)(\n\1(\n.*|$))/\1\2\4/;
  # after searching for previous repeat, move tested last line to end
  s/^([^\n]+)(\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/;
  $!{
   h;
   d;
  };
  # squeeze blank lines to one
  s/(\n){3,}/\n\n/g;
  s/^\n//;
  p;
 ';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be achieved using AWK.

The below line will display unique values:

```
awk file_name | uniq
```

You can output these unique values to a new file:

```
awk file_name | uniq > uniq_file_name
```

The new file *uniq_file_name* will contain only unique values, without any duplicates.

Comment: I think awk is an overkill here.

Comment: This will only remove consecutive duplicates.

Comment: This isn't even *using* awk so much as pretending awk is cat - and even then it's a well-known misapplication - search online for: SC2002 Useless cat

Answer (score -4):

Use:

```
cat filename | sort | uniq -c | awk -F" " '$1<2 {print $2}'
```

It deletes the duplicate lines using AWK.

Comment: This will disturb the order of the lines.

Comment: What is about 20 GB text file? Too slow.

Comment: As ever, [the `cat` is useless.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)  Anyway, `uniq` already does this by itself, and doesn't require the input to be exactly one word per line.