# How to delete duplicate lines in file in unix?

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I can delete duplicate lines in files using below commands:
1) sort -u and uniq commands. is that possible using sed or awk ?

Comment: if you have sort and uniq, why do you want to use sed or awk?

Comment: Well, possible it is, since both are turing complete languages, as far as I recall. The question is what for you'd use them, as pointed by @Skriptotajs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 11):

There's a "famous" awk idiom:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

It has to keep the unique lines in memory, but it preserves the file order.

Comment: This looks awesome but somehow it's not working for me on macOS Sierra.

Comment: only for small files, if file bigger then ram + swap - not worked

Comment: For some definition of "small" . Measured in GB

Answer (score 0):

After sorting we can use this sed command

```
sed -E '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1$/!P; D' filename
```

If the file is unsorted then you can use with combination of the command.

```
sort filename | sed -E '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

Comment: Obviously these alternatives are unacceptable if you can't sort the file.

Answer (score 0):

sort and uniq these only need to remove duplicates
cat filename | sort | uniq >> filename2

if its file consist of number use sort -n

Comment: Though the [`cat` is useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: The `uniq` is also useless.  Just use `sort -u filename`  The `-u` invokes `sort`'s unique mode.  [ None of which answered the OP's question... ]