# Bash Script to remove duplicate lines, only if it duplicates the previous line

Tags: bash, awk

I have files containing lots of lines of data, some of which are duplicated. I want to delete duplicate lines if they follow each other.

For example if the input file contained this:

```
string1
string2
string2
string3
string1
string4
string4
string4
```

I would want the output file to read:

```
string1
string2
string3
string1
string4
```

I am fairly new to bash scripts. I am presuming awk is the way to go but I am a bit stumped. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `uniq` does precisely this.

Comment: @tripleee Should post as an answer!

Comment: So it does! Thanks for the response triplee.  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `uniq` does precisely this.

It is very often used in combination with `sort` so that duplicates will be adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$0==b{next}{b=$0;print}' a.txt
string1
string2
string3
string1
string4
```

I'm using the variable `b` which stands for *buffer*. If the current line is already in the buffer it does not print the line. Otherwise it puts the line to the buffer an prints it.

Comment: You made it, I prefer this to my answer. Good one.

Comment: @fedorqui Thx! The one from anubhava is even shorter as he reverted the logic..

Comment: @fedorqui anubhava's solution is in fact same as yours. in your deleted solution, the `!a[$0]++` doesn't make any sense, you can just remove it, then it would be same as anub..'s.

Comment: @Kent I see... I was thinking in [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix) and then noticed it wasn't the way. But people is so fast here and other better answer were already posted, so I just deleted instead of trying to reformulate it :)

Comment: I also tried posting an answer, I came with same as yours @fedorqui, (without the `!a[$0]++`) then you posted first. I think I should comment your answer, after wrote the comment, you deleted!! and anubhava's answer came, I even thought I can write if check in a positive check, which collided hek2mgls again!.... you guys are too damn fast!!!

Comment: @Kent I hope your brain didn't explode after this situation :D In general, it is always complicated to know what to do. Sometimes we write some answers within a couple of minutes and any small change can make the answer collide with another one... I am learning to delete on the spot, to avoid strange situations. Also, you are so polite commenting first and giving good ideas! :)

Answer (score 2):

This awk should also work:

```
awk '$1!=p{print} {p=$1}' file
string1
string2
string3
string1
string4
```

Or you can shorten this even further:

```
awk '$1!=p; {p=$1}' file
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed. Thanks for the fast response everyone.

Comment: Nice awk solution, although I didn't know about 'uniq' which does just what I want.

Comment: @ghfunk Note that this would only work as long as the _strings_ do not contain any spaces.

Comment: It can be easily changed to use `$0` instead of `$1` for including spaces.

Comment: That might be obvious to those who already know the answer, not to somebody asking this.

Comment: Besides, `awk` is clearly the wrong tool for this specific case and is several times slower than `uniq`.

Comment: @devnull: Just curious if you have run any benchmarks on `sort+uniq` vs `awk`

Comment: `sort` is not even required.  It seems that you need to read the `uniq` manual.  Regarding the benchmarks, there are some statistics available on the linked duplicate.

Comment: So it makes it evident that you need to RTFM.  See `man uniq`.  Just because a flawed answer gathers upvotes doesn't necessarily make it a good or great answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I very well know what `uniq` does and how to use it. I mentioned `sort` since triplee suggested use of `sort` with `uniq`.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses I am learning a lot. uniq does just what I want.

Comment: @ghfunk: Yes `uniq` (without sort) is indeed the simplest solution for your problem.