# How to remove common lines between two files without sorting?

Tags: bash, sorting, optimization, sed, comm

I have two files not sortered which have some lines in common.

file1.txt

```
Z
B
A
H
L
```

file2.txt

```
S
L
W
Q
A
```

The way I'm using to remove common lines is the following:

```
sort -u file1.txt > file1_sorted.txt
sort -u file2.txt > file2_sorted.txt

comm -23 file1_sorted.txt file2_sorted.txt > file_final.txt
```

Output:

```
B
H
Z
```

The problem is that I want to keep the order of file1.txt, I mean:

Desired output:

```
Z
B
H
```

One solution I tought is doing a loop to read all the lines of file2.txt and:

```
sed -i '/^${line_file2}$/d' file1.txt
```

But if files are big the performance may suck.

- Do you like my idea?
- Do you have any alternative to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

grep or awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]' file2 file1
```

Comment: `a[$0]=7` Why equal to seven? Thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnDoe we just need a non-zero number, 7 and 1 have no difference. I change it into 1, if it makes you feel comfortable. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I feel much better now. :)

Comment: Actually this is the best method to do it. Is faster that the grep method. Thank you! :D

Comment: @JohnDoe it should be faster than the grep, because array in awk is hashtable, checking key used hash function, which would be `O(1)`, the grep one needs `O(n^2)` however, my awk line will save file2 in memory. so the space complexity is larger than the grep line.

Comment: This was a lifesaver. awk rocks!

Comment: If `file2` is empty(i.e. `rm -f file2; touch file2`), this awk command won't work

Answer (score 33):

You can use just grep (`-v` for invert, `-f` for file). Grep lines from `input1` that do not match any line in `input2`:

```
grep -vf input2 input1
```

*Gives:*

```
Z
B
H
```

Comment: would it be better if it with option `-F -w or -x` ? e.g. substring case.

Comment: This works to compare whether *entire lines* are equal: `grep -vxf input2 input1`.

Also grep on macOS (grep version 2.5.1) is being weird and doesn't give any results, so i had to use grep from Homebrew which is gnu-grep.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a little Perl script that I use for this kind of thing. It can do more than what you ask for but it can also do what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
my %opts;
getopts('hvfcmdk:', \%opts);
my $missing=$opts{m}||undef;
my $column=$opts{k}||undef;
my $common=$opts{c}||undef;
my $verbose=$opts{v}||undef;
my $fast=$opts{f}||undef;
my $dupes=$opts{d}||undef;
$missing=1 unless $common || $dupes;;
&usage() unless $ARGV[1];
&usage() if $opts{h};
my (%found,%k,%fields);
if ($column) {
    die("The -k option only works in fast (-f) mode\n") unless $fast;
    $column--; ## So I don't need to count from 0
}

open(my $F1,"$ARGV[0]")||die("Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");
while(<$F1>){
    chomp;
    if ($fast){ 
    my @aa=split(/\s+/,$_);
    $k{$aa[0]}++;   
        $found{$aa[0]}++;
    }
    else {
    $k{$_}++;   
        $found{$_}++;
    }
}
close($F1);
my $n=0;
open(F2,"$ARGV[1]")||die("Cannot open $ARGV[1]: $!\n");
my $size=0;
if($verbose){
    while(<F2>){
        $size++;
    }
}
close(F2);
open(F2,"$ARGV[1]")||die("Cannot open $ARGV[1]: $!\n");

while(<F2>){
    next if /^\s+$/;
    $n++;
    chomp;
    print STDERR "." if $verbose && $n % 10==0;
    print STDERR "[$n of $size lines]\n" if $verbose && $n % 800==0;
    if($fast){
        my @aa=split(/\s+/,$_);
        $k{$aa[0]}++ if defined($k{$aa[0]});
        $fields{$aa[0]}=\@aa if $column;
    }
    else{
        my @keys=keys(%k);
        foreach my $key(keys(%found)){
            if (/\Q$key/){
            $k{$key}++ ;
            $found{$key}=undef unless $dupes;
            }
        }
    }
}
close(F2);
print STDERR "[$n of $size lines]\n" if $verbose;

if ($column) {
    $missing && do map{my @aa=@{$fields{$_}}; print "$aa[$column]\n" unless $k{$_}>1}keys(%k);
    $common &&  do map{my @aa=@{$fields{$_}}; print "$aa[$column]\n" if $k{$_}>1}keys(%k);
    $dupes &&   do map{my @aa=@{$fields{$_}}; print "$aa[$column]\n" if $k{$_}>2}keys(%k);
}
else {
    $missing && do map{print "$_\n" unless $k{$_}>1}keys(%k);
    $common &&  do map{print "$_\n" if $k{$_}>1}keys(%k);
    $dupes &&   do map{print "$_\n" if $k{$_}>2}keys(%k);
}
sub usage{
    print STDERR <<EndOfHelp;

  USAGE: compare_lists.pl FILE1 FILE2

      This script will compare FILE1 and FILE2, searching for the 
      contents of FILE1 in FILE2 (and NOT vice versa). FILE one must 
      be one search pattern per line, the search pattern need only be 
      contained within one of the lines of FILE2.

    OPTIONS: 
      -c : Print patterns COMMON to both files
      -f : Search only the first characters of each line of FILE2
      for the search pattern given in FILE1
      -d : Print duplicate entries     
      -m : Print patterns MISSING in FILE2 (default)
      -h : Print this help and exit
EndOfHelp
      exit(0);
}
```

In your case, you would run it as

```
list_compare.pl -cf file1.txt file2.txt
```

The `-f` option makes it compare only the first word (defined by whitespace) of file2 and greatly speeds things up. To compare the entire line, remove the `-f`.