# BASH/sed to remove duplicates from a separated-by-line word list in a text file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a long vocabulary list, one word per line. Sometimes, there is a duplicate word, appearing more than once OR TWICE. I need a simple code that will leave the first occurrence of a word, but remove all duplicates (with its line) after it.

1. I don't want to remove any special characters or rearrange anything, only remove the words (one per line). Keeping the same word order is important.
2. It doesn't matter if it overwrites the original file or saves to a new one, whichever is "more efficient".
3. This is a list separated by line, not an array, not separated by space or comma.
4. I have not code to start with, hoping to solve with BASH...

   - `sed` would be first choice
   - `grep` would be second choice
   - Third choice would be something like a `for` loop

Eg: file.txt

```
apple
banana
car
bicycle
apple
tree
banana
apple
motorcycle
```

...should become:

```
apple
banana
car
bicycle
tree
motorcycle
```

*I see some solutions for ARRAYS, but not simple lists, and answers via python, js, and C languages, but not BASH. If this has already been answered, show me where and I will gladly delete this question. The suggested dupl. article uses `awk`, which is outside of the scope of this question, though it is related and useful.*

Comment: Not a duplicate, that answer is "by comma", this is by line (in my title).

Comment: The *question* mentions commas but many of the answers solve exactly your problem. I can dig for a better duplicate if you like; I'm pretty sure there are multiple questions exactly like this.

Comment: @tripleee: "Keeping the same word order is important.". Most of the solutions there use `uniq`, which requires the file to be sorted. The only solution that addresses this scenario that I noticed is the 2-vote AWK one (not `bash` as the OP suggested would be the preference).

Comment: Okay, using uniq? That didn't answer that specific question about commas, tho. Should I delete my question? Should I make a new question and answer it? I will leave this question a short while, then do what you suggest. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I added another duplicate with more solutions. It's fine to have duplicates, the site will eventually remove the question if it doesn't receive traffic.

Comment: @tripleee That one is a much better dupe target... Just there's no bash solution :) as that question prefers sed/awk.

Comment: @Amadan Then post yours as an answer to that one instead. Having multiple questions with the same topic with different answers is just inefficient and confusing. It's the [DRY principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: [bash remove duplicate lines in a text file site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+remove+duplicate+lines+in+a+text+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @tripleee: I guess I'm a bit more literal-minded - that question says "I want to use `sed` or `awk`", this one says "I see some solutions for [various], but not BASH".

Comment: @Amadan That's a red herring anyway; the OP mentions `sed` and `grep` as possibilities. Questions are not supposed to prescribe an answer in any event; often, the best answer is to change the OP's approach slightly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/remove-duplicate-lines-without-sorting?noredirect=1 has many peculiar answers too.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324350/how-to-remove-common-lines-between-two-files-without-sorting

Comment: @Amadan actually read carefully, ty.

Comment: @tripleee you say questions shouldn't suggest what the answer could include, even for clarity? This wasn't exactly a complex sed/grep lesson. But okay, I'll take that part out just for you.

Comment: That's not a criticism of your question; it's just that when we answer, we often cannot assume that the asker has a good grasp of what a sensible solution should look like.

Comment: @tripleee really, thank you. I really understand what you mean. I feel the love today, with this question I asked, and learned a TON about coding in Linux. It's interesting, I just mailed my US election absentee ballot AND earned my ability to vote on SO, all today. You were part of that and I appreciate what you taught me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 'G;/^([^\n]+\n)([^\n]+\n)*\1/!{P;h}' file
```

Keep a list of unique keys in the hold space and if the current key is not in the list print it and add it to the list.

Comment: This actually answers my question with the "first choice"! WINNER!

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't overly concerned about maintaining the order, you could just use the very simple:

```
sort -u inputFileName >outputFileName
```

This would get rid of all duplicates, sorting in the process.

For *maintaining* the order based on first occurrence, it becomes more complex (and memory hungry). Using associative arrays in `awk` is one way, as per the following example:

```
pax> cat infile
zanzibar
apple
banana
apple
carrot
banana
sausage
apple

awk '{if(x[$1]==0){x[$1]=1;print}}' infile
zanzibar
apple
banana
carrot
sausage
```

The way this works is that `awk` will, the first time it sees a word, store the fact that it's seen it and output the word. Later instances of that word will do nothing because the word has already been marked as seen.

Comment: maintaining order is important, I will edit the question to say this. Thanks for this.

Comment: @JesseSteele -- the `awk` solution does that...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the problem with awk is that I didn't mention it in the original question. BUT, it really did solve the problem simply and has opened my mind to using awk in the future. Previously, awk was not always installed with my Linux distro, but in U 18.04 it seems to be. (FYI, this article was what David referred to, but has been taken down from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377040/remove-duplicate-entries-using-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -g -A lines
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  if [[ "${lines["$line"]}" -ne 1 ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
    lines["$line"]=1
  fi
done
```

EDIT: If you make it into a standalone executable script, you could do it with `dedupe.sh < file.txt`. If you want to hard-code the file name in there, you can do so like this:

```
while ....
  ...
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Now that is a good use of an associative array as a *frequency array*! Strange... I voted for this question and then I guess somebody downvoted, perhaps because the concept of a frequency array is bewildering to them..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well, it's just a seen/not-seen array now, I'm not actually counting anything, though it could be adapted for frequency array very easily.

Comment: Well, you are actually storing `lines["$line"]=1` after each `line` is seen. Which provides the seen/not see check as a 0/1. I guess for a pure frequency array you would need `((lines["$line"]++))` instead of `=1`.

Comment: If you put the `lines["$line"]=1` inside the `if`, it *may* perform better. I'm also not sure how well the performance would be for large files since `bash` read loops are sometimes less than speedy :-) Not worth a downvote of course, since OP didn't specify file size.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks, yeah, that makes sense. (Getting further away from frequency array, sorry David :D )

Comment: @Amadan this is AWESOME, BUT I don't know where file.txt fits into it. Can you edit it or tell me how to make it work that way. This was third choice and I appreciate this knowledge of BASH you shared here! wow.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I also voted for it, now that I can vote!!! (15 today). This answer really did cut to the heart of my OP. Had I not put `sed` as my "first choice" already, I would have made this the "correct" answer. This answer made my question here NOT a duplicate for sure!

Answer (score -1):

Once you sort the file using sort you can then remove adjacent duplicate lines using uniq.

[Man pages uniq](https://ss64.com/bash/uniq.html)

`sort unsorted.txt | uniq >> sorted_deduped.txt`

Comment: The OP very specifically and repeatedly ruled out sorting the file. (And if you do, `sort -u` will beat `sort | uniq`)

Comment: Did mention prefer when I read the question it has been edited since

Comment: The original also had it, though less directly: "I don't want to remove any special characters _or rearrange anything_"

Comment: Obviously not clearly enough as I was not the only person to answer using a sort.

Comment: @Amadan thank you for reading and understanding. Peter has a point that it could be clarified better. But, IMHO, various responses to this question prove that many people on SO skim in their reading ;-) ty