# Deleting the lines which match the output of another unix command

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file as below

```
cat file
a 1 
a 2
b 3
```

I want to delete a 1 row and a 2 row as the first column of it is the same.

I tried `cat file|uniq -f 1`, im getting the desired output. But I want to delete this from the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]==1{print}' file file
```

This one-liner works for your needs. no matter if your file was sorted or not.

### add some explanation:

This one-liner is gonna process the file twice, 1st go record (in a hashtable, key:1st col, value:occurences) the duplicated lines by the 1st column, in the 2nd run, check if the 1st col in the hashtable has `value==1`, if yes, print. Because those lines are unique lines respect to the col1.

Comment: Could you explain how does this work? It looks to me it stores the occurrences of each line and just prints it if no other "similar" line was found.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni I posted something totally wrong just now, it was a copy/paste mistake. Commands look similar, so ... :(  now fixed. thanx for the comment.

Comment: I didn't know it was wrong, I am just learning awk and I was going through it :D Could you please add some comments to explain it?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni added in answer.