# Bash - Remove duplicates preserve order

Tags: bash, sorting, preserve

i have a file that looks like

```
1254543534523233434
3453453454323233434
2342342343223233535
0909909092324243535
```

Is there a way / command in bash to remove duplicates on the file above, based on a specific substring, without changing their order in the output?

ie

(With substring -> ${line:11:8}

```
1254543534523233434
2342342343223233535
0909909092324243535
```

I know that :

```
sort -u : sorts them numerically, then removes duplicates
sort -kx,x -u : The same
cat filein | uniq : requires them to be sorted already or it will not work
```

I m trying to figure out if there's a native linux solution without having to resolve to perl code for it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. It has the additional constraint of comparing lines based only on a subtring, but printing the complete line.
However, the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix) should be easily extendible to `awk '!seen[substr($0, 11, 8)]++' file.txt`.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate;  answers referenced avoid sorting, but they don't preserve order

Comment: Should not be closed ; not a duplicate in any way ; order must be preserved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use awk without any need to sorting:

```
awk '!uniq[substr($0, 12, 8)]++' file

1254543534523233434
2342342343223233535
0909909092324243535
```

- Since awk index starts from `1` you need to use `substr($0, 12, 8)` to get desired 8 characters long text starting from 12th position.
- `uniq` is an associative array with substring retrieved using `substr` function.
- `++` sets value of array as `1`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.