# Get distinct extension list Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am new in Linux and currently I am facing a problem. I want to get list of extensions (.doc, .pdf) from a folder. I googled a lot and finally I get a solution which is given below :

```
 find . -type f | awk -F. '!a[$NF]++{print $NF}'
```

I understand `find . -type f`, but unable to understand `awk -F. '!a[$NF]++{print $NF}'`  what does it mean?

NF = Number of Fields in the current record

Can anyone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following command for this purpose:

```
$find <DIR> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 basename | grep -Po '(?<=.)\..*$' | sort | uniq 
.bak
.c
.file
.file.bak
.input
.input.bak
.log
.log.bak
.out
.out.bak
.test
.test.bak
.txt
.txt.bak
```

where the `find` command will look for all files under the `<DIR>` subtree pass them to `basename` to get only their filename without the path part (`-0`, and `-print0` are used to take into account files with spaces in their names), then you `grep` only the part of the string that starts with a `.` (the extension .tar, .txt, .tar.gz) and also it ignores the hidden files with their name starting with `.`. After that you sort them and get only the unique values.

If you do not need the starting `.` in the extension name add

```
| sed 's/^\.//'
```

Comment: Thanks I got what you said, Can you please explain what does 'awk' means?

Comment: Hope it helps you! Yeah sure: in brief `awk` is a programming language used to manipulate text file in a column way, you can use it to do computation, or filtering ;-) It is very powerful but you need a bit of time to learn it since it is a whole programming language by itself ;-)

The awk command you are using use `.` as field separator and does print the last field of each line if it has not already been print (using an `awk` array to do that and increasing the value of the cell indexed by the extension)

Comment: However do not use that command since it will fail in many cases if you have hidden files for example or extensions with several `.` ;-) like `.tar.gz` what is really common in Unix world

Comment: The name `awk` means Aho, Kernighan, and Weinberger, which are the names of the inventors/initial programmers, and Kernighan is the K in Kernighan & Ritchie, who are known for inventing the Language C.

Comment: The `-print0 | xargs -0 -n1 basename` can be replaced with `-printf "%f\n"`. In most cases '-print0 | xargs -0` is better replaced with one of the `-exec`-variants (-exec, -execdir, -ok, -okdir) because it keeps the find-chain alive and it is just useless to pipe the output to another command, which just iterates over files as find already does. Except your find lacks the -exec-options.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question what the `awk` line is doing :

As you already indicated, the line `find . -type f` returns a list of files located in the current directory. Eg.

```
./foo.ext1
./bar.ext2
./spam.ext2
./ham.ext3
./spam.ham.eggs
```

This list of files is send with a pipe to the command `awk -F. '!a[$NF]++{print $NF}'`. This awk line contains a lot of information. First of all you need to know that awk is a record parser where each record consists of a number of fields. The default record is a `line` while the default field separator is a sequence of spaces. So what does your awk line do now :

- `-F.` :: this redefines the field separator to be a dot (`.`). From this point forward all lines in the example have now 2 fields (eg line 1 `foo` and `ext1`) while the last line has 3 fields (`spam`, `ham` and `eggs`).
- `NF` :: this is an `awk` variable that returns the number of fields per record. It is clear that the extension is represented by the last field (`$NF`)
- `a[$NF]` :: this is a array where the index is the extension. The default array value is `zero` unless you assign something to it.
- `a[$NF]++` :: this returns the current value of `a[$NF]` and increments the value with 1 after the return. Thus for line 1, `a["ext1"]++` returns `0` and sets `a["ext1"]` to `1`. While for line 3, `a["ext2"]++` returns `1` and sets `a["ext2"]` to `2`. This indicates that `a[$NF]` *keeps track of the amount of times `$NF` appeared*.
- `!a[$NF]++` :: this combines the logic of the above but checks if return value of `a[$NF]++` is `0`. If it is `0`, return `true` otherwise return `false`. In case of line `2` of the example, This statement will return `true` because `a["ext2"]++` has value `0`. However, after the statement `a["ext2"]` has the value 1. When reading line 3, the statement will return `false`. In other words, *have we seen `$NF` already? And while you answer this question with "yes" or "no" increment the count of `$NF` with one.*
- `!a[$NF]++{print $NF}` :: this combines everything. It essentially states, *If `!a[$NF]++` returns `true`, then `print $NF`, but before printing increment `a[$NF]` by one.* Or in other words, If the field representing the extension (`$NF`) appears for the first time, print that field. If it has already appeared before, `do nothing`.

The incrementing of the array is important as it keeps track of what has been seen already. So line by line the following will happen

```
foo.ext1       => $NF="ext1", a["ext1"] is 0 so print $NF and set a["ext1"]=1
bar.ext2       => $NF="ext2", a["ext2"] is 0 so print $NF and set a["ext2"]=1
spam.ext2      => $NF="ext2", a["ext2"] is 1 so do not print and set a["ext2"]=2
ham.ext3       => $NF="ext3", a["ext3"] is 0 so print $NF and set a["ext3"]=1
spam.ham.eggs  => $NF="eggs", a["eggs"] is 0 so print $NF and set a["eggs"]=1
```

The output is

```
ext1
ext2
ext3
eggs
```

**General comments:**

- A file without any extensions al or not in a hidden directory (eg. `./path/to/awesome_filename_without_extension` or `./path/to/.secret/filename_without_extension`) or a part its full path printed as if it was the extension. The result however is meaning less, i.e.

  ```
  /path/to/awesome_filename_without_extension
  secret/awesome_filename_without_extension
  ```

  This is best resolved as

  ```
  find . -type f -exec  basename -a '{}' + \
    | awk -F. '((NF>1)&&(!a[$NF]++)){print $NF}'
  ```

  Here the output of find is processed directly by `basename` which strips the directory from the filename. The awk line does one more check, do we have more then 1 field (i.e. is there an extension).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way of doing what you are attempting is to `sort` the output keeping only unique extensions, e.g.

```
find . -type f -regex ".*[.][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | \
awk -F '.' '{ print $NF }' | sort -u
```

if your `sort` doesn't support the `-u` option, then you can pipe the results of `sort` to `uniq`, e.g.

```
find . -type f -regex ".*[.][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | \
awk -F '.' '{ print $NF }' | sort | uniq
```

The `-regex` option limits the `find` selection to filenames with at least one ASCII character extension. However it will also pickup files without an extension if they contain a `'.'`, e.g. `foo.bar.fatcat` would result in `fatcat` being included in the list.

You could adjust the regular expression to meet your needs. If your version of `find` supports *posix-extended* regular expressions then you can prevent longer extensions from being picked up. For example to limit the extension to `1-3` characters, you could use:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}$" | \
awk -F '.' '{ print $NF }' | sort -u
```

There are other ways to approach this, but given your initial example, this is a close follow-on.

Comment: Nice answer+1! However what do you do with the hidden files? and the files with extension like `.tar.gz`?

Comment: Yes, that is the sticky wicket. You can always adjust your regex in as wild of ways as you need. As is -- it does handle hidden file natively, but would not handle extensions with multiple parts such as `.tar.gz`. (doable -- just much longer regular expressions and `awk` logic)