# How to remove duplicate commands from Bash history file?

Tags: bash

I have configured my own `.bash_myhistory`

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "

export HISTFILE=~/.bash_myhistory
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

When I run `history` it shows me many repetitive output:

```
 $ history | grep 'git rebase'
   75  [2018-05-23 16:39:39] git rebase -p dev_hypermouse 
  168  [2018-05-23 19:27:39] man git rebase 
  547  [2018-05-25 19:01:44] git rebase master 
  639  [2018-05-25 20:24:52] git rebase master 
  869  [2018-05-28 14:07:33] git rebase xxx
  921  [2018-05-28 16:12:20] git rebase dash_v2 
  922  [2018-05-28 16:12:33] man git rebase
  925  [2018-05-28 16:13:21] man git rebase
  927  [2018-05-28 16:15:42] git rebase xxx dash_v2 
  937  [2018-05-28 16:17:46] git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
 2177  [2018-05-23 16:39:39] git rebase -p dev_hypermouse 
 2270  [2018-05-23 19:27:39] man git rebase 
 2649  [2018-05-25 19:01:44] git rebase master 
 2741  [2018-05-25 20:24:52] git rebase master 
 2971  [2018-05-28 14:07:33] git rebase xxx
 3023  [2018-05-28 16:12:20] git rebase dash_v2 
 3024  [2018-05-28 16:12:33] man git rebase
 3027  [2018-05-28 16:13:21] man git rebase
 3029  [2018-05-28 16:15:42] git rebase xxx dash_v2 
 3039  [2018-05-28 16:17:46] git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
 4239  [2018-05-23 19:27:39] man git rebase 
 4618  [2018-05-25 19:01:44] git rebase master 
 4710  [2018-05-25 20:24:52] git rebase master 
 4940  [2018-05-28 14:07:33] git rebase xxx
 4992  [2018-05-28 16:12:20] git rebase dash_v2 
 4993  [2018-05-28 16:12:33] man git rebase
 4996  [2018-05-28 16:13:21] man git rebase
 4998  [2018-05-28 16:15:42] git rebase xxx dash_v2 
 5008  [2018-05-28 16:17:46] git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
 ...
```

But `$ cat ~/.bash_myhistory | grep 'git rebase'` does not:

```
man git rebase 
git rebase master 
git rebase master 
git rebase xxx
git rebase dash_v2 
man git rebase
man git rebase
git rebase xxx dash_v2 
git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
man git rebase
man git rebase
history | grep git rebase
history | grep 'git rebase'
```

How to fix repetitive output from `history`?

**UPD**

with `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` history looks much better but duplicates still exists:

```
$ history | grep 'git rebase'
   34  [2018-05-23 19:27:39] man git rebase 
  413  [2018-05-25 19:01:44] git rebase master 
  505  [2018-05-25 20:24:52] git rebase master 
  735  [2018-05-28 14:07:33] git rebase xxx
  787  [2018-05-28 16:12:20] git rebase dash_v2 
  788  [2018-05-28 16:12:33] man git rebase
  791  [2018-05-28 16:13:21] man git rebase
  793  [2018-05-28 16:15:42] git rebase xxx dash_v2 
  803  [2018-05-28 16:17:46] git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
 2038  [2018-06-02 14:49:31] man git rebase
 2058  [2018-06-02 14:52:33] man git rebase
 2060  [2018-06-02 15:11:08] history | grep git rebase
 2061  [2018-06-02 15:11:13] history | grep 'git rebase'
 2063  [2018-06-02 15:12:45] cat .bash_myhistory | grep 'git rebase'
 2064  [2018-06-02 15:09:58] man git rebase
 2077  [2018-06-02 15:35:41] history | grep 'git rebase'
 2111  [2018-05-23 19:27:39] man git rebase 
 2490  [2018-05-25 19:01:44] git rebase master 
 2582  [2018-05-25 20:24:52] git rebase master 
 2812  [2018-05-28 14:07:33] git rebase xxx
 2864  [2018-05-28 16:12:20] git rebase dash_v2 
 2865  [2018-05-28 16:12:33] man git rebase
 2868  [2018-05-28 16:13:21] man git rebase
 2870  [2018-05-28 16:15:42] git rebase xxx dash_v2 
 2880  [2018-05-28 16:17:46] git rebase --onto dash_v2 xxx 296-ToS-component 
 4115  [2018-06-02 14:49:31] man git rebase
 4135  [2018-06-02 14:52:33] man git rebase
 4137  [2018-06-02 15:11:08] history | grep git rebase
 4138  [2018-06-02 15:11:13] history | grep 'git rebase'
 4140  [2018-06-02 15:12:45] cat .bash_myhistory | grep 'git rebase'
 4141  [2018-06-02 15:09:58] man git rebase
 4154  [2018-06-02 15:35:41] history | grep 'git rebase'
```

**UPD**
Even after adding `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` history looks like:

```
25988  [2018-07-26 17:13:19] gd 1
25989  [2018-07-26 15:45:47] mc
25990  [2018-07-26 13:57:46] mc
25991  [2018-07-26 09:23:28] mc
```

Also I notice that some commands disappear from history =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

From bash man page:

> ### HISTCONTROL
>
> A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list. If the list of values includes ignorespace,
>   lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history
>   list. A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous history
>   entry to not be saved. A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for
>   ignorespace and ignoredups. A value of erasedups causes all previous
>   lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list
>   before that line is saved. Any value not in the above list is ignored.
>   If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines
>   read by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject to the
>   value of HISTIGNORE. The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line
>   compound command are not tested, and are added to the history
>   regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.

Comment: with this history looks much better, but duplicates still exists. What you can advice more?

Comment: Try `awk '!seen[$0]++' file.txt` where file.txt is `.bash_history`. Make sure and take a **backup** first! :-) From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444448/470530).

Comment: That works (except it not delete times for preceding line). But this will not save from future duplicates

Comment: The bash history `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` will avoid future duplicates!

Comment: I'll fire up my Linux box at home this evening and check it out. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I assume this removes/ignores adjacent duplicates, not all duplicates (Right?)