# how to remove repeated rows in awk

Tags: awk

I have a big text file like this example:

`example`:

```
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
```

there are some repeated lines and I want to take only one repeat of them. for the above example the expected output would look like this:

```
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using the following command:

```
awk myfile.txt | uniq > uniq_file_name.txt
```

but the output is empty. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: your command fails because `awk` fails. you did not specify what awk needs to do. If `myfile.txt` is just your output, then you could do `uniq myfile.txt`. This will remove consecutive lines which are duplicates. If you want to remove all lines which are duplicates, you can do `awk '!a[$0]++' myfile.txt`. Remark these are two completely different solutions.

Comment: With repeated, do you mean consecutively repeated or just remove the duplicates form the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix (accepted answer but also comment under question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Since hek2mgl sir mentioned in case you need to remove continuous similar lines then try following.

Let's say following is Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
```

Run following code now:

```
awk 'prev!=$0;{prev=$0}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
```

---

---

The following snippet will remove all duplicate lines, not only repeating lines

```
awk '!a[$0]++'  Input_file
```

Append `> output_file` to above command in case you want to take output into a separate file.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now. This is only for explanation purposes for running code use above mentioned one only.

```
awk '
!a[$0]++      ##Checking condition here if current line is present in array a index or NOT, if not then increase its value by 1.
              ##So that next time it will make condition as FALSE, since we need to have only unique lines.
              ##awk works on method of condition and action, so if condition is TRUE it will do some action mentioned by programmer.
              ##Here I am not mentioning action so by default print of current line will happen, whenever condition is TRUE.
'  Input_file  ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This will remove all duplicated lines, not _repeated_ lines

Comment: @hek2mgl, I thought OP needs to remove duplicates, let me add another case too now.

Comment: @hek2mgl, sir, I have added EDIT solution now, by taking an example Input_file please correct me if I missed something here.

Comment: I would rephrase `Could you please try following` by `The following snippet will remove all duplicate lines, not only repeating lines`

Comment: @hek2mgl, sure done now, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

Your command:

```
$ awk myfile.txt | uniq > uniq_file_name.txt
```

and more precisely this part:

```
$ awk myfile.txt
```

will hang as there is no program or script for awk to execute. The minimum you need to do to print all the lines is:

```
$ awk 1 myfile.txt
```

But since you had no awk script, I assume you don't need awk, then just use `uniq` (depending on your need, either):

```
$ uniq myfile.txt
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
```

or

```
$ sort myfile.txt | uniq
```

which for that input will produce the same output.

**Update**:

Regarding the discussion in the comments about *why sort*: If *repeated lines* means *all duplicated records* in the file, use `sort`. If it means *consecutive duplicated lines* forget the `sort`.

Comment: I would remove the `sort myfile.txt  | uniq`. It's misleading and pointless because it will only produce the same output when the input is already sorted. But why use `sort` then?

Comment: Well, those few sample lines might be in sorted order but I don't know about the rest.

Comment: Yeah, that's why the anwer to `how to remove repeated rows` is `uniq`, not `sort | uniq`

Comment: Why not  `sort -u`?

Comment: because that will remove all duplicates, not just repeated lines

Answer (score 2):

This is to show the difference between `uniq`, `awk '!a[$0]++'` and `sort -u`.

**`uniq`:**  removes the consequitive duplicate lines, keeps order :

```
$ echo "b\nb\na\nb\nb" | uniq
b
a
b
```

**`awk !a[$0]++`:** removes all duplicates, keeps order

```
$ echo "b\nb\na\nb\nb" | awk '!a[$0]++'
b
a
```

**`sort -u`:** removes all duplicates and sorts the output

```
$ echo "b\nb\na\nb\nb" | sort -u
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
> cat user106.txt
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
> perl -ne ' print if $kv{$_}++ == 1 ' user106.txt
chr1    109472560   109472561   -4732   CLCC1
chr1    109477498   109477499   206 CLCC1
>
```

To remove repeated lines

```
> echo "a\nb\nb\nb\nc\nc\nd\na" | perl -ne ' print if $prev ne $_ ; $prev=$_ ' -
a
b
c
d
a
>
```

Comment: This will remove all duplicated lines, not only repeated lines

Comment: ok - looks like some discussions happened after I posted.. let me work on it