# Remove duplicate lines based on starting pattern using bash

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a list of Jira tickets that follow the following syntax:

```
XXXX-12345: a description
```

where 12345 is a pattern like [0-9]+ and the XXXX is constant. For example, the following list:

```
XXXX-1111: a description
XXXX-2222: another description
XXXX-1111: yet another description
```

should get cleaned up like this:

```
XXXX-1111: a description
XXXX-2222: another description
```

I've been trying using `sed` but while what I had worked on Mac it didn't on linux. I think it'd be easier with `awk` but I'm not an expert on any of them.

I tried:

```sh
sed -r '$!N; /^XXXX-[0-9]+\n\1/!P; D' file
```

Comment: Replacing `$0` with `$1` in the accepted answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444406/1331399) should do the trick

Comment: Can you show your attempted code?

Comment: @Thor Thanks! it worked. Could you explain the command to me, please? I understand the idea behind using awk '!seen' but I don't understand why $1 or how it identifies the pattern in my use case.

Comment: @JuanVega: awk splits each line into fields according to what `FS` is set to, it defaults to sequences of spaces and tabs. This splitting sets the positional variables `$1`, `$2`, ... accordingly, so `$1` is the first field, up-to the first space/tab

Comment: @anubhava I was trying to use `sed -r '$!N; /^XXXX-[0-9]+\n\1/!P; D'` as I found another answer where it was used to delete duplicated lines. In the original answer instead of `XXXX-[0-9]+` there was `(.*)`. But it's sure I don't get how it works because it doesn't work.

Comment: @Thor Ok, now I understand. So in my case it works basically because there is always a space after `:`. So if I want to make it work by splitting by the first colon to avoid lines without whitespaces I should use `awk -F ':' '!seen[$1]`, right? I was confused because while searching for information I saw use cases that were using $0 instead of $1.

Comment: @JuanVega: You can just use `awk '!seen[$1]++' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple `awk` should get the output:

```sh
awk '!seen[$1]++' file

XXXX-1111: a description
XXXX-2222: another description
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up using that one as also suggested by @Thor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the digits are the only thing defining a dup, you could do:

```
awk -F: '{split($1,arr,/-/); if (seen[arr[2]]++) next} 1' file
```

If the `XXXX` is always the same, you can simplify to:

```
awk -F: '!seen[$1]++' file
```

Either prints:

```
XXXX-1111: a description
XXXX-2222: another description
```

Comment: Thanks! I keep that first one in mind if the characters end up changing at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 'G;/^([^:]*:).*\n\1/d;P;h' file
```

- `-nE` turn on explicit printing and extended regexps.
- `G` append unique lines from the hold space to the current line.
- `/^([^:]*:).*\n\1/d` If the current line key already exists, delete it.
- `P` otherwise, print the current line and
- `h` store unique lines in the hold space

N.B. Your sed solution would work (not as is but with some tweaking) but only if the file(s) were sorted by the key.

```
sed -E 'N;/^([^:]*:).*\n\1/!P;D' file
```

Comment: I didn't add the code but yes, I had lines sorted first before using my no solution. I'm curious, is the solution you propose the tweaking I would need? I'm not an expert on regex expressions so, what does that regex do exactly to only use the XXXX-1234 part in the comparison?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @JuanVega in regexp you can group matching parts by enclosing them in parens. You can then refer to these grouping by a back reference which are numbered starting from the left most paren. e.g. /(aaa)(bbb)\1\2/ would match the string aaabbbaaabbb and /((aaa)bbb)\1\2/' would match aaabbbaaabbbaaa. Thus the regexp /^([^:]*:).*\n\1/ would match the same key twice and in the solution above, would delete that line. HTH BTW the first solution works sorted or unsorted the second only when sorted