# Remove all but the first line containing a given string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a log file called `duration.log` with output such as

```
2021-04-15 20:25:45.639181: --- DURATION: 0:00:02.928309 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:25:48.756914: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.000727 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:25:51.948027: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.068122 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:25:55.075158: --- DURATION: 0:00:02.987064 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:25:58.274715: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.063948 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:26:01.753367: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.273167 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:26:05.001949: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.050073 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-15 20:26:08.206065: --- DURATION: 0:00:03.073367 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:03:24.188722: --- DURATION: 0:00:21.995238 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:03:50.434883: --- DURATION: 0:00:26.140902 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:04:18.552286: --- DURATION: 0:00:27.793468 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:06:27.015632: --- DURATION: 0:00:33.688867 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-829-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:07:10.487733: --- DURATION: 0:00:42.421573 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-830-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:07:39.247244: --- DURATION: 0:00:28.391001 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-831-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:06.292683: --- DURATION: 0:00:26.790946 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-832-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:29.929427: --- DURATION: 0:00:19.462734 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-833-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:53.306396: --- DURATION: 0:00:23.140965 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-834-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 ---
```

I removed duplicate lines using `awk '!seen[$0]++' duration.log` found in
[How to delete duplicate lines in a file without sorting it in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix).

Now, how do I remove all but the first line containing the string `210415-821-PK-JDoe`? Awk or other bash tools.

#### Update:

I'm looking for a following output:

```
2021-04-15 20:25:45.639181: --- DURATION: 0:00:02.928309 --- ROUTE NAME: 210415-821-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:03:24.188722: --- DURATION: 0:00:21.995238 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:03:50.434883: --- DURATION: 0:00:26.140902 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:04:18.552286: --- DURATION: 0:00:27.793468 --- ROUTE NAME: None --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:06:27.015632: --- DURATION: 0:00:33.688867 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-829-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:07:10.487733: --- DURATION: 0:00:42.421573 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-830-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:07:39.247244: --- DURATION: 0:00:28.391001 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-831-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:06.292683: --- DURATION: 0:00:26.790946 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-832-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:29.929427: --- DURATION: 0:00:19.462734 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-833-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 --- 
2021-04-16 09:08:53.306396: --- DURATION: 0:00:23.140965 --- ROUTE NAME: 210416-834-PK-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 0 ---
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post sample expected output also in your question for little more clarity on your expected output, thank you, cheers.

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples.

```
awk '/210415-821-PK-JDoe/ && ++count>1{next} 1'  Input_file
```

OR as per Sundeep's comment above could be written as:

```
awk '!/210415-821-PK-JDoe/ || !count++'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
/210415-821-PK-JDoe/ && ++count>1{   ##checking condition if line contains 210415-821-PK-JDoe AND count is greater than 1 then do following.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                    ##1 will print current line here.
'  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: you can simplify it to `awk '!/210415-821-PK-JDoe/ || !c++'`

Comment: @Sundeep, sure, thank you, I have added the solution now, cheers.