# Bash- getting rid of duplicate chars from a set in output

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, duplicates

Scenario 1:
I have a variable where this string is contained:

```
    output="abdh748mdn78##j*&#"
```

the special characters belong to a set called specialchars

```
    specialchars='@#$%&*+-='
```

All I want for Christmas is to

1) keep one of the specialchar, discard the rest.

2) delete multiple occurrence of that one char from the string, or alternatively- just choose ONE of the special chars and discard the rest.

Scenario 2:

```
    output="a#bdh#748m#"

    Speicalchar="$char" [where $char is '#' randomly selected from set- look above]
```

notice there are multiple #'s

Just need to get rid of the duplicate and keep one.
Then echo $output

I tried:

```
    echo $stringout | sed 's/\([@#$%&*+-=]\)\1/\1/g'
```

found it on stackx but it doesn't work.

Need to keep it bash (can only use bash utils).

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: expected input- scenario 2: a#bdh#748m# Output - a#bdh748m. for Scenario 1 input abdh748mdn78##j*&# Output- abdh748mdn78#j.

Comment: why you fail to leave the `*` and `&` in the second one..

Comment: because they belong to a special character set [@#$%&*+-=]. specification is to display only one of the character from the set, and with no duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicated characters from string in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402740/how-to-remove-duplicated-characters-from-string-in-bash)