# Removing contiguous duplicate lines in vi without sorting

Tags: regex, vim, vi, duplicate-data

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351161/removing-duplicate-rows-in-vi) already addresses how to remove duplicate lines, but enforces that the list is sorted first.

I would like to perform the remove contiguous duplicate lines step (i.e. `uniq`) without first sorting them.

Example before:

```
Foo
Foo
Bar
Bar
```

Example after:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just found the solution [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Uniq_-_Removing_duplicate_lines). The following regex works correctly:

```
g/^\(.*\)$\n\1$/d
```

Answer (score 23):

```
:%!uniq
```

if you're on a unix system, or a system that has the `uniq` program

Comment: Good suggestion, I should have mentioned in the question that I'm on Windows (and no Cygwin).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to remove non-contiguous duplicates you could use

```
:g/^\(.*\)\ze\n\%(.*\n\)*\1$/d
```

(which will remove all but the last copy of a line)

which would change

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
Bar
Foo
Baz
Foo
Quux
```

to

```
Bar
Baz
Foo
Quux
```

If you want to remove all but the first copy, try

```
:g/^/m0
:g/^\(.*\)\ze\n\%(.*\n\)*\1$/d
:g/^/m0
```

which would change

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
Bar
Foo
Baz
Foo
Quux
```

to

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
Quux
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove **contiguous** duplicate lines, just use uniq without sorting anything.

```
:%!uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/\1/ge
```

this is my answer for you

Answer (score -4):

I know this is old, but it's worth mentioning the following also works if you don't mind sorting as well (I know the OP wanted to avoid it):

```
:sort u
```